# Wife/Family lied to me before getting Nikkah

Tags: nikah, talaq

I just recently got Nikkah done barely 4 weeks ago.

My wife has been divorced before. According to her , the last husband use to verbally abuse her and left her for another woman.

we knew each other for 3 months before the nikkah and things were going fine. 
After the Nikkah it turns out that she had a lot of issues related to her first marriage they are all psychological in nature . she never got proper treatment for them. She lives in Pakistan , her family is very traditional and seems like they didnt want the world findnout she had psychological issues. although she is a doctor herself she was self medicating her self and she was also taking Anti-Depressants before and stop taking it recently.

Now She has a lot of anger issues , and compares me to her Ex all the time. Anything that happens between us is quickly related to her past and she refuses to be rational, her episode of anger go on for a full day. 
She also constantly asks for divorce. I know I have issues also but I have tried to work out things but things don't seem to calm down.

before the Nikkah and engagement I told her all my issues and anything related to my past. . I was never told of any issues relating to her condition (taking anti-depressants and anger issues, etc ). In my opinion at this time she is a person with severe issues .

I need guidance on if I can divorce her because of her and her family hiding her condition before the nikkah.

Wsalam.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help). Questions that solicit opinion-based answers are typically closed. Please try to rephrase your question to make it more Islam-specific.

Comment: The question as is sounds to me like an advice-request which are hardly on-topic here, because they are too broad or attracting opinion-based answers. From a shari'a perspective you could easily divorce maybe even nullify the nikah with this lady because of these lies. But you should have in mind that Allah when speaking about the relationship between spouses always use the exoressuon "if you fear..." and this lady seem to need help and apparently you are the person who see this clearly and as a husband you should support her as good as you can...

Comment: Lets me remind you that "new research has shown that half the people who take antidepressants for depression never get relief." http://blog.timesunion.com/holistichealth/antidepressants-widely-used-but-practically-useless/14468/

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to make an agreement if possible that you will resolve any issue relating to any argument or dispute by returning to Quran and sunnah.
2. Refer her to a good doctor and give her time of few months for medications to have its effects fully.
3. It was wrong on part of family of bride to conceal any mental health issues of bride.
4. Approach a ahle hadith imam/ mufti for counselling. Below link might be helpful in your case.
5. Always make istekharah before any important decision in life.

https://islamqa.info/en/23472